# How to get three.js sprite background to blend?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using sprites in three.js to load a texture for points (previously pointcloud) and I cannot get the blending to work properly. Here is the code I am using:

```
this._renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
this._renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
....
new THREE.Points(geometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial({transparent: true,  blending: THREE.CustomBlending, blendSrc: THREE.OneFactor,  blendEquation: THREE.AddEquation, map: lt._sprite, size: 1, vertexColors: true}));
```

The sprite contains the disc.png sprite that comes with threejs. This is how it looks:

- custom blending (code above): [threejsblending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn8YN.jpg).
- no blending: [no blending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMeaf.jpg)

different blendings I used looks either the same as one of the above and/or the sprite is not loaded correctly (square points).

I am not super familiar with threejs or webgl. Any help is appreciated. The whole code is long and complicated but I can post any part that is relevant.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone running into the same problem, what fixed it for me was:

```
alphaTest: 0.5
```

passed to the pointsmaterial.

```
new THREE.PointsMaterial({transparent: true, alphaTest: 0.5, ....);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set the background of your sprite - disc.png - to transparent.  So that way, the round object in your sprite will have whatever color you want but the corners will be transparent.  Here are instructions to do so using Paint.net:

http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/19145-convert-image-to-transparent-background/

Make sure you save your new sprite as a .png file.  It also looks like you are missing an opacity setting in your THREE.PointsMaterial call.  So in addition to setting "transparent: true", if you want your colored discs to have some transparency, you will need set opacity to some value between 0.0 and 1.0, such as "transparent: true, opacity: 0.4, ***"  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. 
The background is indeed transparent. I am using the textures from three.js itself and it clearly works for some of the points and not on others. 
I finally figured it out last night. It has to do with alphaTest.